# Thread-bound work queue for tasks dequeuing extra work if current item(s) are awaiting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Right, terrible title but I can't for the life of me think of a succinct description. I'm trying to think if it's possible to create a work queue of asynchronous work items (Tasks), which

1. Shall be processed by a given set/pool of threads (which I would like to spawn/control myself)
2. A thread dequeuing work shall also be responsible for actually executing it
3. There should be no "downtime". Meaning, if a thread dequeues a task, starts running it, but the task ends up await'ing some IO or such, the same thread should in the meantime try dequeuing another task & start running it

Let's look an example. Assume a shared queue of work:

```
ConcurrentQueue<Func<ValueTask>> _queue = new();
```

In practice, the Tasks in the queue could take on any form of course. For the sake of running through an example (!), let's say they all do the same thing, namely:

```
static async Task DoSomething()
{
    synchronous_work_that_takes_5_seconds();       // line 1
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSecond(7));      // line 2
    synchronous_work_that_takes_1_seconds();       // line 3
}
```

Now let's say I spawn just one thread consuming work from this queue. This is how it should behave:

|  | Thread 1 |
| --- | --- |
| t = 0 | Dequeue and start work item #1 |
| t = 5 sec | Work item #1 DoSomething() hits line 2, i.e. awaiting Task.Delay The thread should now be available to do other work, so: Dequeue and start work item #2 |
| t = 10 sec | Work item #2 DoSomething() hits line 2. Work item #1 is still in await state, so can't be resumed yet, so: Dequeue and start work item #3, and is now in await state |
| t = 15 sec | Work item #3 DoSomething() hits line 2. Work item #1 is done with its await and can be resumed, so: Resmue work item #1 (line 3) |
| t = 16 sec | Work item #3 is now complete. Work item #2 and #3 are still awaiting, so.. Dequeue and start work item #4 |
| t = 21 sec | Work item #4 hits line 2 (Task.Delay) Work item #2 is done with the await and can now be resumed, so: Resume work item #2 (line 3) |
| t = 22 sec | Work item #2 is complete Work item #3 has just finished its await, so: Resume work item #3 |
| t = 23 sec | Work item #3 is complete. Work item #4 is still stuck await'ing, so... Dequeue work item #5 |
| ... | ... etc ... |

I don't have a lot of great ideas to do this at the moment. I thought "maybe I can bend a custom task scheduler this way somehow", but it looks tricky as dequeuing (scheduling) new work depends on the state of the thread itself, and the state of all currently enqueued tasks.

Is something like this even possible? I'd appreciate any pointers.

---

For context, why am I thinking about such a weird approach? Because in practice, i'd expect the vast majority of work items to actually be fully synchronous (ValueTask used on purpose here), and would like the bind their execution to a specific thread for cache friendliness.

However, there might be the occasional oddball task that actually is asynchronous, and potentially needs to await I/O stuff for a quite a while; ideally, of course, I'd like to keep churning on all other work if and while that is the case.

Comment: Personally I would handle this with the CQRS pattern, and have a cache singleton to deal with multi-threaded caching.  What you're trying to do sounds overly complicated, you basically want a Queue that's synchronous but also not synchronous all on the same thread, and you're going to end up with some function that does way too much and becomes overly complex. You could just have an event queue with event handlers, that know how to deal with each event, and all pull from a cache singleton.

Comment: What should happen in case a thread dequeues a task, starts running it, the task ends up await'ing some I/O, and after the completion of the I/O there is more work that needs to be done? Which thread should complete this work? The initial thread that dequeued the task? Any thread from your custom thread pool? Any thread including the threads of the native `ThreadPool`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The thread that dequeued it, at its "next" convenient opportunity. (when more than 1 task on that thread need continuation, it'd ideally first continue with the one it dequeued first. That order is not crucially important though)

Comment: This article may help you implement the custom `TaskScheduler`s needed to achieve your goal: [ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/) ([code](https://github.com/donatasm/ParallelExtensionsExtras/tree/master/src/TaskSchedulers))

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, I was being an idiot. I somehow assumed TaskSchedulers would only be used to queue the initial task. But they're indeed used to (re-)queue resumptive work as well. Should be easy to implement then! Thanks